# How to make available one ASP.NET docker container to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, docker

I have two services in my solution, which are ASP.NET projects. One of them making actions with database(service named Topics), and another should be a gateway. I am deploying to docker both services with Visual Studio and not writing any commands to run projects.

In Topics service in **Launchsettings.json** i am defining ssl and http port, and while it runs in docker i can use this service in browser with no problem by address https://localhost:port/something_here.
Here it is a part of **Launchsettings.json** in Topics service:

```
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/topics",
      "httpPort": 44381,
      "sslPort": 44382,
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
```

But later, when i trying to contact from Gateway service(which is another one docker container) i am receiving an error, that it can't contact my Topics service.
In Gateway i am trying to connect to **http://localhost:44381/topics** and **https://localhost:44382/topics** and from none of them i can't receive an answer.

What should i do to be able to connect my docker containers on my localhost?

Comment: Have you read through background material like [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, but i am not using Compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final way to solve my problem was to run docker doing build and exposing port manually. Visual Studio was doing something wrong, which caused that it was possible to connect to container manually, but impossible with another docker container. So it was mistake to use built-in way to run docker in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is a reserved hostname that always should refer to the machine itself. Within a Docker container, localhost will refer to its own container, not to the host computer. If you want to connect to another Docker container, you can use the hostname of the Docker container.

The hostname of a Docker container is usually the container name, but I saw a container created by Visual Studio does not have the container name configured as Alias on the network. If you use docker-compose as described on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/tutorial-multicontainer?view=vs-2019, it is probably a lot easier. Otherwise you might be able to set a hostname via the *commandLineArgs* property in *launchSettings.json*.

If you have a container FrontEnd and and container Topics, you can connect from the FrontEnd container by using https://topics. Now please be aware the portnumber is probably also different than the one you are using now! You https://localhost:44382 is probably forwarded to https://topics:443 (since 443 is the default https-port, this is identical to https://topics).

Edit: don't get confused if you also want to do AJAX-calls. In that case the call is done from your browser, which is running on the Host OS in which case you need to use https://localhost:44382 again.

Comment: It isn't clear how to get  ```{ServiceHost}``` from LaunchSettings. Now i am able to get configuration variables from appsettings to work with them in code, but how is it possible to get ServiceHost from launchsettings?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, the `{ServiceHost}` is just localhost, but you need the name of the container. I have to take a look into that.

Comment: I updated my original answer with this information and removed the reference to `{ServiceHost}`, because it might cause confusion.

Comment: I tried to use https://topics:443 and http://topics:80 and it didn't help. In case of http it is still not able to connect and in case of https it gave me an error of troubles while establishing SSL connection. I think it is unsolvable problem and i should try to move to Docker Compose.